# How to change JSF tag attribute

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Primefaces datatable.

```
<p:dataTable id="updateStaffTable" var="staff" value="#{staffBean.staffs}"  
                         selection="#{staffBean.selectedStaff}" selectionMode="single"
                         paginator="true" lazy="true" styleClass="dataTableSize" rows="10" >
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{staffBean.onRowSelect}"   
                    update=":updateStaffForm:updateStaffPanelGrid" oncomplete="PF('updateStaffDialog').show()" /> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Now, I want to disable selection attribute if the user is not permitted. I can check the user's permissions programmaticly. I also have a bean to check that but I can't use rendered attribute here. How can I do that or is there any other good approach in order to do that?

Comment: do you want not to render some rows inside datatable?

Comment: I have CRUD permissions. If the user has only read permission he shouldn't select the row. I want to make him see data but not update and delete data. When the user select a row, a dialog window opens in order to make update and delete operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use EL in the attribute the usual way like as you did for other attributes. You can use the conditional operator `?:` to perform an if-else in EL.

E.g. set to `single` only when user has the role `ADMIN`:

```
selectionMode="#{request.isUserInRole('ADMIN') ? 'single' : null}"
```

---

As to the other answer suggesting `binding` for this, it is **not** recommended to use `binding` whenever the functionality is just possible purely in the view side. You can even just do `selectionMode="#{bean.selectionMode}"` if you really need to control it from the bean on. Try to avoid `binding` on a backing bean property as much as possible unless you need to dynamically populate components which for some unclear reason can't be done in view side (with JSTL you can do a lot).